# java - handling NullPointerException in java when function has to return some value of generic datatype

Tags: java

Here is my code:

```
public E get(int index)
{
    LLNode<E> current = head;
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i <= index; i++) {
            if (current != null) {
                current = current.next;
            }
        }
        return current.data;
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        throw e;
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        // How do I handle this?
    }
}
```

How do I handle the `NullPointerException` when I have to return something of type E?I am testing my code using JUtil. I am a beginner and am finding this part tough to understand, please help.

EDIT : I am testing this function using JUtil function whose (partial)code is given below :

```
// Test empty list, get() should throw an exception
try {
    emptyList.get(0);
    fail("Check out of bounds");
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

here emptylist is an Empty List object created from a personally created LinkedList Class. How do I solve for this (//test empty list, get should throw an exception) as in this case the foremost mentioned get function returns NullPointerException? Please help me.

New Code :

```
public E get(int index)
    {
        // TODO: Implement this method.
        LLNode<E> current = head;
        for(int i=0; i<=index; i++)
        {
            if(current != null)
            {
                current = current.next;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
            }
        }
        return current.data;
    }
```

After running "New Code", these are the results and errors are on the bottom left panel :
[image: After running tests on new code]

Comment: If you don't know how to handle an exception, you shouldn't catch it.

Comment: Either return null or don't catch the exception.

Comment: Both of those exceptions are `RuntimeExceptions` and should rarely be explicitly caught. Instead, you should take measures to prevent either of those exceptions from being thrown in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chances are you're looking to throw the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` here instead of catching it.

There are some clear reasons to:

- Your code *shouldn't* be throwing any `NullPointerException`s, as the only place that this could realistically occur is if `current == null`, and that's ideally when you want to throw the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Rewritten without the `try...catch`, your code would look something like this:

```
public E get(int index) {
    // TODO: Implement this method.
    LLNode<E> current = head;
    for (int i = 0; i <= index; i++) {
        if (current != null) {
            current = current.next;
        } else {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }

    }
    return current.data;
}
```

Comment: I have added an image after applying your solution, please help me further!

Comment: If you have a new question, you should post it as a new question, not add it to this one.

Comment: I am sorry, just that I am really tensed. Sorry

Answer (score 2):

Simple, do not handle it.

Your code will throw `NullPointerException`, only if the last value assigned to `current` is `null`, as your check for `current != null` does not encompass the return value `current.data`.

As is, it will not throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, although you *might* want to throw it programmatically (see Makoto's answer).

You should add a check there.

Generally, you don't want to catch `NullPointerException`s but rather check for `null` values and act upon.

Also, your method *may* return `null` if the last value of `current` is not `null`, but its `data` property is, which should be checked upon invocation and assignment of its returned value to a reference, if needed.

**Edit**

If you need to programmatically throw an exception upon failure (e.g. `current.data` is `null`, or any criterion you deem fit within context), you can do so in two "and a half" ways:

- A checked exception, custom or not (in which case you'll need to declare you're throwing it after your method signature)
- A runtime exception
- A runtime exception wrapping around a checked exception, so you don't need to declare it

Comment: I have edited my question. Can you please help me now because I am explicitly told to 'throw' exceptions.

Comment: @MohitGarg if you need to throw an exception upon failure, you can programmatically do so. It all depends on the conditions for the failure, and which exception you want/need to throw.

Answer (score 0):

Better not to get into the situation of a `NullPointerException` being thrown in the first place.

As soon as `current` is `null`, you have run out of elements in the list. So throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, since your index is literally out of bounds of the list.

(And there is no need to catch and rethrow `IndexOutOfBoundsException`: just remove your try/catch)

Answer (score 0):

by the looks of things, you're code can't ever actually generate a NullPointerException (the only object that could be null is "current" - but you null check for that)...so this block doesn't really serve a purpose (not sure if the IndexOutOfBoundsException can be hit either).

let's pretend it can though and first answer your question directly - probably the most meaningful return value for the NullPointer (NPE) block is "null" itself.

```
catch (NullPointerException e) {
    return null;
}
```

logically and design-wise this probably doesn't make sense - you would probably be better off throwing an Exception instead of returning something here.  Let's say, for example, that "head" was null and that somehow led to a NullPointerException - it may not make sense for get(index) to throw a NullPointer in this case - it may instead make more sense to throw something like an IllegalStateException instead.

```
catch (NullPointerException npe) {
     // head isn't initialized correctly...it should be
     throw new IllegalStateException("LLNode is not correctly initialized", npe)
}
```

this PARTICULAR case ends up also being bad design (it's better to check for null...like you are already doing!...vs. intentionally catch a NUllPOinterException)...but don't be scared to catch one exception in order to throw a more meaningful one